# Minimal package for TFS API

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget

I need my C# desktop application to create TFS work items depending on my data.It should not use any further functionality: only connect to tfs and create workitems\tasks. I think solution of this problem should be simple and dont use a lot of code and a lot of referenced libs.

According to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet  i should use these nuget packeges.

In https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130322(v=vs.120).aspx article supposed to use *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common* and
*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client* libraries.

I'm a bit confused what to use, because in first case the memory overhead is too big(all libs = 60Mb when my app is only 10Mb) and a lot of redundand packages are used(some webapi, soap,sazure fetures).In second one i can't find them except as a parts of different packages.

**I don't need help about write code, i need advice about least weight functional package to do this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the option to use the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview) instead of client libraries. This will remove the need to reference the Microsoft TFS libraries, but you might need other packages like Json or something.

For example, a call to `https://{instance}/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workitemtypename}?api-version={version}` will create a WorkItem ([source](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items#Createaworkitem))

Comment: I agree this is lighter but at the cost of maintaining your own copy of the TFS object model and likely more troubleshooting to get it right initially.  More development time versus small package.

Comment: This is absolutely true. Was just putting the option out there :-)

Answer (score 0):

That Nuget package includes lots of assemblies for all aspects of TFS (SourceControl, Builds, WorkItems, etc).  You can add the Nuget package to your project but only reference the assemblies you actually need for Work Items and that should cut down the size of your compiled application package.